# Why is this control flow graph correct?

Tags: java

Given the following method written in Java:

```
private void collatz(List<Integer> values) {
     int size = values.size();
     if (size == 0 ||
              values.get(size=1) <= 1) {
              return;
     } else {
        int last = values.get(size = 1);
        if (last%2 == 0) {
           values.add(last/2);
        } else {
           values.add(3*last+1) ;
        }
        collatz(values);
   }
}
```

My textbook gives the following CFG for the code:

[image]

Where each vertex describes the corresponding line of code.  Why is this correct? What I don't understand is the edge between the vertex $13$ and the end vertex, shouldn't this edge be from $13$ to $2$ instead, since we're recursively calling the function? Would really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often control-flow graphs don't include call's or other interprocedural control-flow in the graph.  So, a call node does not lead to an edge from the call site to the callee, and in this case, that means there would be no edge from 13 to 2.